# How to check Trustline Authorized Flag?

Tags: trustline, stellar-sdk, flags

I need to check if an account trustline is authorized or not (before payment)

Eg: this account https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GDT43XDX4VP7JPJUXRZO7JJH4PHJRCXYFPJA5PJPQC4MLLTF6PEEY5JU has COP but the trustline has authorized flag set to false.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [operations-for-account](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/operations-for-account.html) endpoint will list all operations for that specific account incl. changes to the trustlines.

If you scroll to the bottom on this [stellar laboratory page](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=operations&endpoint=for_account&values=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiR0RUMzdaQkFERExVTkxFRVNXWEVHWlZHSVpYUUVESTZGSEVCTVVGR0xIR1BJM1ZJREQzREdOWlAifQ%3D%3D&network=test) (after clicking submit) it will show you the following operation which changed the authorize flag to false:

```
  {
    [...]
    "id": "41852832801886209",
    "paging_token": "41852832801886209",
    "source_account": "GDT37ZBADDLUNLEESWXEGZVGIZXQEDI6FHEBMUFGLHGPI3VIDD3DGNZP",
    "type": "allow_trust",
    "type_i": 7,
    "created_at": "2018-06-29T01:35:13Z",
    "transaction_hash": "1405516165b1e39b108cadd1c0c3b09baaea8edd9d536a1b679cca510e52b549",
    "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
    "asset_code": "COP",
    "asset_issuer": "GDT37ZBADDLUNLEESWXEGZVGIZXQEDI6FHEBMUFGLHGPI3VIDD3DGNZP",
    "trustee": "GDT37ZBADDLUNLEESWXEGZVGIZXQEDI6FHEBMUFGLHGPI3VIDD3DGNZP",
    "trustor": "GDT43XDX4VP7JPJUXRZO7JJH4PHJRCXYFPJA5PJPQC4MLLTF6PEEY5JU",
    "authorize": false
  }
```

I'm not aware of an easier way to find this information at the moment. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/159) to simplify this.

Comment: `balances` object under GET /accounts/:id now has a `is_authorized` to validate if trustline exists (source - same issue link mentioned in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use stellar.expert as that is quite easy in interface. If an account has created trustline, it will show balance 0 for that asset in the explorer.

Comment: thanks but I need a way using horizon not external tools

Comment: You can also do it using horizon, basically check if asset_code is true and asset_type is not native than that account has COP(asset) trustline. Authorized flag is a setting, with which the anchor must approve anyone who wants to hold its asset, allowing it to control who its customers are.

Comment: thanks but for eg.. this account https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GDT43XDX4VP7JPJUXRZO7JJH4PHJRCXYFPJA5PJPQC4MLLTF6PEEY5JU will return true with that validation but authorized flag is false and cant do transactions with COP

Comment: That does not show the required flag.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked my way around it by logging the accounts to which I send an AllowTrust operation. When sending payments, I always do the AllowTrust however I skip the accounts I logged in my CSV file.

Note: This is not a best practice. I'm a big fan of including an authorized boolean in the balances array of the output.